# Transferring data from one SQL table layout to a 'new & improved' one

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-migration

The project I work on has undergone a transformation at the database level. For the better, about 40% of the SQL layout has been changed. Some columns were eliminated, others moved. I am now tasked with developing a data migration strategy.

What migration methods, even tools are available so that I don't have to figure out each every individual dependency and manually script a key change when their IDs (for instance) change.

I realize this question is a bit obtuse and open ended, but I assume others have had to do this before and I would appreciate any advice.

I'm on MS SQL Server 2008

**@OMG Ponies** *Not obtuse but vague:*

Great point. I guess this helps me reconsider what I am asking, at least make it more specific. How do you insert from multiple tables to multiple tables keeping the relationships established by the foreign keys intact? I now realize I could drop the ID key constraint during the insert and re-enable it after, but I guess I have to figure out what depends on what myself and make sure it goes smoothly.
I'll start there, but will leave this open in case anyone else has other recommendation.

Comment: Not obtuse, but vague.  What changes in the data are you having to deal with?  Don't need a tool to write up `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an upgrade script that morphs the current schema into the v. next schema, applying appropriate operations (alter table, select into, update, delete etc). While this may seem tedious, is the only process that will be testable: start from a backup of the current db, apply the upgrade script, test the result db for conformance with the desired schema. You can test and debug your upgrade script until is hammered into correctness. You can test it on a real data size so that you get a correct estimate of downtime due to size-of-data operations.

While there are out there tools that can copy data or transforms schema(s) (like [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare)) I believe approaching this as a development project, with a script deliverable that can be tested repeatedly and validated, is a much saner approach.

In future you can account for this [upgrade step in your development and *start* with it](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/), rather than try to squeeze it in at the end.

Answer (score 1):

there are tons of commercial tools around that claim to solve this -> i wouldn't buy that...

I think your best bet is to model domain classes that represent your data and write adapters that read in/serialize to the old/new schemas.

If you haven't got a model of your domain, you should build one now.

ID's will change, so ideally they should not carry any meaning to user's of your database.